# Java Commons Collections removeAll

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons-collection

[CollectionUtils::removeAll() Commons Collections 3.2.1](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29)

I must be going crazy, becuase it seems like this method is doing the inverse of what the docs state:

> Removes the elements in remove from collection. That is, this method returns a collection containing all the elements in c that are not in remove.

This little JUnit test

```
@Test
public void testCommonsRemoveAll() throws Exception {
    String str1 = "foo";
    String str2 = "bar";
    String str3 = "qux";

    List<String> collection = Arrays.asList(str1, str2, str3);
    System.out.println("collection: " + collection);

    List<String> remove = Arrays.asList(str1);
    System.out.println("remove: " + remove);

    Collection result = CollectionUtils.removeAll(collection, remove);
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
    assertEquals(2, result.size());
}
```

Is failing with

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2> but was:<1>

and prints

```
collection: [foo, bar, qux] 
remove: [foo] 
result: [foo]
```

From my reading of the docs I should expect `[bar, qux]`. What have I missed?

Comment: I updated my post to reflect this since someone reminded me of it - but Apache Commons Collections 4.0 was released in November 2013, with a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Edit January 1, 2014** Apache Commons Collections 4.0 was finally released on November 21, 2013, and contains a fix for this issue.

[Link to `CollectionUtils.java`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/collections/tags/COLLECTIONS_4_0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.java?view=markup)

Lines in question (1688 - 1691), with acknowledgement the method was previously broken:

```
/*
 ...
 * @since 4.0 (method existed in 3.2 but was completely broken)
 */
public static <E> Collection<E> removeAll(final Collection<E> collection, final Collection<?> remove) {
    return ListUtils.removeAll(collection, remove);
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

Nope, you're not crazy. `removeAll()` is actually (incorrectly) calling `retainAll()`.

This is a bug in `CollectionUtils`, affecting version 3.2. It's been fixed, but only in the 4.0 branch.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COLLECTIONS-349

And as further proof, here's a link to the source code:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/collections/tags/COLLECTIONS_3_2/src/java/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.java

Check out this line:

```
public static Collection removeAll(Collection collection, Collection remove) {
    return ListUtils.retainAll(collection, remove);
}
```

Yep...broken!

Comment: Holy smokes! How did that slip through the cracks? Thanks for the info. Upvote and accept for you.

Comment: @markdsievers - Looks like either unit tests are needed, or need fixing!

Comment: IMO, this is pretty poor.  Mistakes are OK, but the original issue has a creation stamp of "02/Aug/06 17:37", and they STILL haven't made a production release with the fix in it.

Comment: @StephenC - It's extremely poor, even a patch release would be better than waiting for a release of the trunk, and the last time Apache Commons Collections saw a release was version 3.2.1 in April 2008. Maybe no one thinks this is a big deal, or they don't know it's broken and there are problems in code bases everywhere.

Comment: For anyone interested, my solution was to use the intent of this method directly, ie ListUtils.removeAll(a,b).