# Java - remove objects in a collection that are in another collection, with an arbitrary meaning of "equals"

Tags: java, collections, equals

This is very easy if I just want to base this on absolute equality. I'd just do:

```
collectionA.removeAll(collectionB).
```

However, let's say I have this object:

```
class Item {
   private String color;
   private String name;
   private String type;
}
```

And two collections...

```
List<Item> items1, List<item> items2.
```

...but I just want to remove everything from item1 that has the same *name and type* as something in item2.

Note that I can't subclass or define equals, hashcode for this class.

I'd want this to be the same complexity of the existing collections.removeAll method.

The best solution I can think of would be something like:

```
class SimpleItem {
  String name;
  String type;
  Item item;

  public SimpleItem(Item item) {
    this.name = item.getName();
    this.type = item.getType();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    ...
  }
}

Set<SimpleItem> simpleItems1 = ...;
for (Item item : items1) {
  simpleItems1.add(new SimpleItem(item));
}

Set<SimpleItem> simpleItems2 = ...;
for (Item item : items2) {
  simpleItems2.add(new SimpleItem(item));
}

simpleItems1.removeAll(simpleItems2);

Set<Item> items = ...;
for (SimpleItem simpleItem : simpleItems) {
  items.add(simpleItem.item);
}
```

...but that is insanely verbose. It's Java 8. What clever solution am I missing?

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to do, but if you want to filter some elements from `Collection` you could do something like `persons.parallelStream().filter((Person p)-> {return p.getAge() > 18;});`

Comment: @keyser If my implementation seems right, I guess I'll stick with it. It just seems like so much text for a pretty simple operation.

Comment: @Jeremy I kinda missed the part about needing to wrap it. Hopefully you can do something like what Joshi suggested instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention that it's Java 8. In that case you have a very simple and straightforward way to achieve this:

```
list1.removeIf(item1 -> list2.stream().anyMatch(item2 -> customEquals(item1, item2));
```

If your `customEquals` method is a member of `Item` you could use a method reference to make it a bit neater:

```
list1.removeIf(item -> list2.stream().anyMatch(item::customEquals));
```

In your case you could put your condition directly into the statement rather than creating a separate method:

```
list1.removeIf(item1 -> list2.stream().anyMatch(item2 ->
    item1.getName().equals(item2.getName()) && item1.getType().equals(item2.getType())));
```

Conveniently `removeIf` is a default member of the `Collection` interface so any class that implements `Collection` should support it as long as the implementation's iterator supports `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) class to do so. Good examples are [here](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/10/join-two-list-in-java)

[Another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372576/java-commons-collections-removeall)